# How to access ShellViewModel in an Caliburn.Micro application?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application with Caliburn.Micro. The main ViewModel is ShellViewModel. It contains a tab control, and each tab contains a user control. I need to access a property of ShellViewModel from that internal user control.

var par = ((MyApp.ShellViewModel)((Screen)Parent).MyProperty;

ShellViewModel is not known though. Could you please tell how I can access it?

Thanks.

Comment: My question is - why? Maybe there is a better way to do what you want, so what is it that you need to inspect this property for?

Comment: @Charleh Because the behavior depends on some selections made on the main screen (ShellView).

Comment: Does each tab also have a viewmodel?

Comment: Yes, each tab also has a viewmodel.

Comment: Can you explain what the property is for, it sounds like maybe you should use event aggregator or pass the shell vm into the tab vm as a reference

Comment: A property is the selecteed ComboBox string. It defines what is to be displayed in one of the tabs. I don't know what event aggregator is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok from your comments it sounds like you have a combobox on the shell which needs to affect what is displayed on one of the tabs.

To communicate between your ViewModels, you can always use the `EventAggregator` which is part of CM and implements a subscriber pattern which you can take advantage of

e.g.

On your shell VM you can create a static instance of the aggregator or create a separate static class which will provide the aggregator to the application

```
static class AggregatorProvider 
{
    // The event aggregator
    public static EventAggregator Aggregator = new EventAggregator();
}

class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>
{
    // When the combo box selection changes...
    public void SelectionChanged(object SomeValue) 
    {
        // Publish an event to all subscribers
        AggregatorProvider.Aggregator.Publish(new SelectionChangedMessage(SomeValue));
    }
}
```

You handle the `SelectionChanged` of the combobox by using a standard action message or convention (I'm not sure what conventions CM applies by default to the combo so I'll show the explicit bindings in my example)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectionChanged(MyCombo)" />
```

Hopefully if the correct conventions are applied, you should get the selected item being passed to the method

Your child VM just needs to subscribe to the aggregator and implement IHandle where T is the type of message it should handle

```
class ChildViewModel : Screen, IHandle<SelectionChangedMessage>
{
    public ChildViewModel() 
    {
        // Subscribe to the aggregator so we receive messages from it
        AggregatorProvider.Aggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    // When we receive a SelectionChangedMessage...
    public void Handle(SelectionChangedMessage message) 
    {
        // Do something with the new selection
    }
}
```

The `SelectionChangedMessage` can just be:

```
class SelectionChangedMessage 
{
    public object NewValue { get; private set; }

    public SelectionChangedMessage(object newValue) 
    {
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

Obviously the above could be a generic type so that you strongly type the `NewValue` parameter - then again the message you publish can be anything, so it's up to you

It might be worth pointing out that you can `Unsubscribe` from the aggregator so you can control when it receives notifications. The aggregator uses weak references anyway so you don't need to worry too much about unsubscribing, but it does mean you have control over when your objects receive messages (i.e. stop listening when the are not active by subscribing on `OnActivate` and unsubscribing on `OnDeactivate`).

Answer (score 2):

```
var parent = IoC.Get<ShellViewModel>();
```

I can't verify that syntax at the moment but I think it's correct.

Comment: The problem is that ShellViewModel is not known from there:Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ShellViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you exporting it?  Actually, above should probably be `<IShell>`

Comment: Yes, I do:    [Export( typeof( IShell ) )]
   public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive, IShell, IHandle<IStatus>, IStatus
But IoC.Get<IShell>(); returns null

Comment: Is everything in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple projects in the same solution.

Comment: You probably need to override SelectAssemblies.

Comment: I used that Aggregator from another answer, and it worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: True, there are a few ways to solve it.  For what you're doing I personally like injecting a `SharedViewModel` singlton into the Shell and it's children instead of using the `EventAggregator`.  Though it's answered I thought you might want to know why `IoC.Get` wasn't working.  Cheers.